# Непонятная ошибка при работе приложения

Tags: android, java

```
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.qbit.tkdsparring.Biog.onCreateActionView(Biog.java:25)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.ActionProviderWrapper.onCreateActionView(ActionProviderWrapper.java:23)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionView(MenuItemImpl.java:574)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:154)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:432)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1043)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:87)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:187)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:244)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:941)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:964)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:431)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2833)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    ... 29 more
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02002a
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2793)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    ... 32 more
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020033
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1925)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    ... 37 more
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.addLayer(LayerDrawable.java:197)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:168)
08-27 13:32:22.737: E/AndroidRuntime(18101):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.cre
```

Добрый день! Возникла следующая проблема -первый раз столкнулся с такой ошибкой, не могу понять, почему она происходит. Вот код:

```
public class Biog extends ActionProvider
{
    private final Context   mContext;

    public Biog( Context context )
    {
        super( context );
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView()
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from( mContext );
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.biog, null );
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById( R.id.button );
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                mContext.startActivity( new Intent( mContext, BiogActivity.class ) );
            }
        } );
        return view;
    }

}
```

Вылетает на этой строке:

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.biog, null );
```

Буду очень признателен, если подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: хмл покажи

Comment: а вылетает не всегда, а в непонятные моменты времени?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у Вас в селекторе **`abs__list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark.xml`**
 одно из состояний не инициализируется а именно 2 строчка данного xml.

не создается LayerDrawable,

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_pressed_holo_dark"  />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_longpressed_holo"  />
</transition>
```

это стандартная поставка Sherlock - могу предположить, что Вы как взяли ее  из коробки так и используете значит реальной ошибки нет,так что возможно если вы работаете из eclipse попробуйте сделать следующее и в таком порядке

**refresh**

**clean project**

если не помогло

**restart**

Answer (score 1):

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Походу ошибка на 2ой строчки xml -я

Comment: ага, второй строке **бинарного** xml.

Comment: Да скорее всего там затесался какой-то бинарный символ... Человек не кажет исходники - а без этого никак

Comment: я скорее всего знаю ответ, xml здесь ни при чем. Человек не отвечает на мой комментарий выше.

Comment: Ога, там видимо ссылка на класс виджета/кОнтрола, который отсутствует в сырцах :)